# Operating System not found. Error on installing Ubuntu 13.04!

Tags: usb

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 13.04 using boot-able USB disk. but it says that `operating system not found`. and there isn't any problem with the USB disk because it is working well on other machines. I'm using dell xps 15z.

Comment: How did you create the USB stick?

Comment: by ubuntu Startup Disk Creator.

Comment: If you still want to try USB, try Using [Yumi](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your BIOS is complaining about the lack of a MBR on the flash drive. Try updating your BIOS, as it probably doesn't support USB boot, then try installing.

Alternatively, just make a DVD.